# Number Input Broken on Gatsby Forms

Tags: reactjs, forms, gatsby

I'm trying to build a user form with Gatsby, and the "number" input type won't update its value when typing in the field.

```
export default class FormPage extends React.Component {
    state = {
        width: 1920,
        height: 1080,
    }

    handleInputChange = event => {
        const target = event.target;
        const name = target.name;
        const value = target.type == 'number' ? parseInt(target.value) : target.value;
        this.setState({
            [name]: value,
        });
    }

    render() {
        return <input type="number" value={this.state.width} onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
    }
}
```

In this case, the expected default value of 1920 shows up, but when clicking on the input field and trying to type, there is no change; I can't delete any digits, and nothing I do changes the 1920 shown in the input field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add name to the input element so that is why you are getting empty when trying to access event.target.name

Try this:

```
  render() {
      return <input type="number"  name="width" value={this.state.width} onChange={(e)=>this.handleInputChange(e)}/>
  }
```

Here is the working example:https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-roentgen-zoifg